# JTable header using <html> and <br> tag to show ellipsis when column too small

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable

I have the following TableCellRenderer, it is able to display the icon and table header in 2 rows, but the problem is when i resize the column smaller, instead of displaying "..." ellipsis, the words simply gets clipped. Is there any way i can have the multi-line and ellipsis at the same time? I set nowrap because if the column becomes too small, the header gets wrapped into 4 or 5 rows which my header is only rendering 2 rows of text.

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    if (value instanceof JLabel){
        JLabel l = (JLabel) value;
        l.setIcon(icon);
        l.setText("<html><div style='white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;'>My header text <br>is quite long</div><html>");

        return l;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Swing's html rendering support is stuck a html 3.2(?) or there abouts, so it may simply not support the styles you're trying to apply

Comment: You might like to also explain why the default behaviour doesn't work for you, as it seems to produce `...` just fine for me without an additional configuration

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer, my code works for you? You're able to have the header with icon, 2 rows, and ellipsis? When i reduce my column width, instead of ellipsis appearing, it simply clips my text. I'm not sure why either.

Comment: No, doing nothing works for me - if just use `new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(...))` with no custom renders, when I reduce the column size, the text gets appended with `...` until there's nothing left but `...`

Comment: 1) Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. 2) Maybe use a JPanel as the renderer. You could then created multiple labels to display the text so you don't need to use HTML.